# flv to mp3 converter

Tags: c#

hey im writing a c# flv2mp3 converter and i could need some help.
flv is a container type, wich means that when i get all audio tags together, i just have have to reassemble them, or do i habe to save them in a special way? is it possible at all?
and i do not want any flvextractors i wanna do it by myself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What if the soundtrack is AAC or some other format?

You can ignore the timestamps on the audio packets (since the audio timestamps give cues to the video, and don't represent clock-time - the spec is wrong(!) in this respect).  Just extract the raw data from the audio-packets, decode from whatever it happens to be to PCM (at an appropriate sample rate, and appropriate stereo/mono; what if the soundtrack varies?), re-encode as MP3 and you're done.

Its easiest to just use ffmpeg as others have indicated.

Comment: in this case ill use lame.exe

Comment: really, much better to use ffmpeg and let ffmpeg use liblame if appropriate.

Comment: maybe youre right...
but how can I throw the work of 2 weeks away??

Answer (score 0):

If this is an open source app you could look into [ffmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org/)..

Comment: thats not what i wanted!
i just wanted to know if its enough to put the audiotags together or do i have to do this in a special way?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example with SWF Scout

[Example](http://www.bytescout.com/swfscout_example_c_sharp.html)

The sad part about this example...it is not open source libary.

Edit:
As far as i understand the hole theme...you have to get the FLV to SWF and try to reassamble it. 
there are already some open Source solutions...but they seem dirty.